# jQuery after load complete event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using `.load()` and `.show()` to dynamically load some HTML.

```
//load the html
$('#mydiv').load('some_url');
        
            
 // Display
$('#mydiv').show();
```

But here I need to call a  JavaScript function that only exist in the dynamic content, how can I tell if the `.load()` is complete ?

Comment: `.load()` accepts a callback function.

Comment: I think your javascript function will be available once your 

$('#mydiv').load('some_url');

finishes executing.

Answer (score 41):

Use the callback for [.load](http://api.jquery.com/load/):

```
$('#mydiv').load('some_url', function() {
    // This gets executed when the content is loaded
    $(this).show();
});
```

Answer (score 7):

The load function get a callback function for complete

```
('#mydiv').load('some_url', function() {
  alert( "Load completed." );
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/load/

Answer (score 5):

```
$( "#mydiv" ).load( "url", function() {
  alert( "Load was performed." );
});
```

reference [load](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#mydiv').load('some_url', function(responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest){
  console.log("Content Loaded!");
});
```

Look at [this](http://api.jquery.com/load/)